# A problem in converting lyx to pdf after miktex update

Tags: lyx

I updated miktech 2.9 and since that I can't convert my lyx files (any of them) to pdf due to external problems: The first one appears inside folders the are written with spaces and states that there are "spaces" in my folders and due to that the pdf can not be open. The other one states that I should check the logs ("The external program pdflatex finished with an error. It is recommended you fix the cause of the external program's errr (check the logs)") and it appears in folders that are written without spaces. I use lyx version 2.3.3. Any ideas what happend and what seems to be the problem? what are logs?

Comment: the logs (log-files) are files containing messages from application. They can be used to find clues about why something errors or don't work. But you seem to have no idea how miktex works, so it will be very difficult to help you without access to your computer. Better try to find some local support.

Comment: I also have no idea what the problem is. One thing you could try is to upgrade LyX to the latest version. There have been a lot of bug fixes since 2.3.3.